# Is "linear function" in linear algebra different from "linear function" in calculus? If so, why not use different words?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, terminology, definition

Taking a single-variable function as an example, it seems to me linear function in linear algebra (also called linear transformation) is a function $f(x)$ that satisfies $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and also $f(ax) = a f(x)$.  But in Calculus a function will be called linear if it is of the form $f(x) = ax + b$.  If this straight line passes through the origin, then it actually matches the linear algebra sense of the term.

Comment: ["One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA&feature=youtu.be&t=296) -- Richard Feynman

Comment: If $f(x)=ax+b$ with $b\ne 0$, the function is said "Affine".

Comment: Yes, those are different concepts.   Yes, it would be nice if different words had been used but that doesn't always happen.  (Note, by the way, that in Linear Algebra the term "linear transformation" is more often used than "linear function".

Comment: And in abstract algebra courses, a polynomial is called linear when it is of the form $aX+b$ for $a \not= 0$.

Comment: Linear function is linear because its graph is a line. Linear transformation is linear because it preserves linear structure - the structure of vector space. I don't know when precisely the terms were coined, but certainly not at the same time. You don't go and change all the old names just because new objects of interest are discovered. And maths is quite old, there are lots of historical names that could have been better chosen, from our point of view. In most cases, there will be no confusion because there is always some context. Even if there is, it can be clarified with a simple question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are different. In calculus (and high school mathematics before that), a linear function is defined as a map which takes $x$ to $mx+c$ for constants $m,c$. In linear algebra, we further restrict $c=0$. More precisely and generally, we say a function $f$ is linear if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y$ in the vector space we are working in ($\mathbb R^n$ for example), as well as $f(cx)=cf(x)$ for all $x$ in the vector space we are in, and $c$ in the underlying field (think $\mathbb R^n$ with underlying field $\mathbb R$) we are in. You can tell that this definition rules out $x\mapsto mx+c$ with $c\neq0$. In the context of linear algebra, if we wanted to allow the constant to be nonzero, we call the mapping *affine*.